# jQuery this var outside of anon function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to achieve something like this. Any ideas?

```
function test(that){
    $(that).blur();
}

$("#form").focus(test(this));
```

Comment: why not just use .focus(function() { $(this).blur(); )};  or something like that

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish?  This code looks like you're attempting (though you have coding errors in it) to assign an event handler to the focus event that then triggers the blur event.  The code isn't actually doing that because .focus(test(this)) is calling test(this) immediately, not setting up an event handler.  You would need something like this .focus(function() {test(this)}) to do that.  But, even if you do that, I'm not following what you're actually trying to accomplish and whether this would do that?

Comment: I want to use `this` in a regular defined function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass `focus` a function. You are putting a function *call* inside it, and that is returning `undefined`.

```
function test(){
    this.blur();
}

$("#form").focus(test);
```

Don't blur elements onfocus though — it creates major accessibility issues and effectively prevents anyone from navigating past the element without a pointing device.

Comment: I understand and acknowledge the accessibility issues, what I'm doing has a unique way of interacting with the form without conventional typing.

Comment: Could you point me to a doc or explain, the difference of calling a function via test vs test(). I'm a little confused to how this works with anon functions.

Comment: `test` is a function. `test()` is a function call. `foo = test` makes `foo ``a reference to the same function as test. `foo = test()` executes test and assigns whatever value it returns to `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do this ?

```
.focus(function() { 
$(this).blur();
 )};
```

Comment: Yeah, this is the standard way of doing it but I wanted to us this inside another function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `#form` is the id of a form, you'll need to put the focus listener on the input:

```
function test(obj)
{
    $(obj).blur();
}

$('#form input').focus(function()
{
    test($(this));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
$("#form").focus(function(){
  test(this);
});
```

This is because event handlers must be functions, it means that the argument of the `.focus()` method has to be a function, you cannot write code "directly" in the parameter as you did.

Hope this helps.